# Memory leak when reading multiple large files in Python

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, ram

I'm facing memory issue **loading multiple textual files**.

I decided to split a very large file in 30 smaller ones, to better handle them. These files are about **1.7GB** and my RAM is **28GB**. My purpose is to read the lines of each file and update a counter, then read the lines of the next file and so on.

```py
for filename in filenames:
    tracemalloc.start()
    with open(path + '/' + filename) as file_reader:
       lines = file_reader.readlines()
    print(f"Read {filename}: {len(lines)} lines")
    for line in tqdm(lines):
        counter.update(list(line))
```

I have seen that after the line: `lines = file_reader.readlines()` **my RAM occupation increases of 3GB after every step**, so after 9 iterations the process is killed.

I tried to print the occupation of the local variables with `sys.getsizeof` method, but they don't seem to reach these values, so I tried to use the garbage collector with `gc.collect()` but it didn't change anything.

I don't understand if some memory of the files are kept after every iteration or if the variables `lines` and `counter` reach higher values compared to what I'm seeing with `sys.getsizeof`.

Any ideas?

Comment: would it not be better to iterate over the original file in chunks?

Comment: @Chris I thought to do so, to manually split the file in chunks and avoid memory leaks, hoy would you write the code instead?

Comment: @PaoloMagnani instead of extracting all the lines, then iterating over them, you can do one line at a time : `for line in file_reader.readlines()`, so you don't need to have the whole file in memory, just one line at a time. But the problem will be your `counter` that stores a growing copy of what you have have read so far, I don't think it is a memory leak, it does exactly what is expected. Either you should find another way to do what you want, or find more RAM.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing this from memory of something I did 30 years ago.

Here is a simple way to operate on the 51 GB file in the shell.
All you need is a lot of disk space, and don't need ram.

cat file | sort -T /tmp | uniq -c > out.results

If you sort the 30 smaller files separately,
you can use mergesort by using the -m flag to sort.

You do realize that the counter.update is a hash table
and not an integer, correct?  If each file is 1.7GB,
it is not surprising that each file takes up 3GB in
memory.  It can't take less than 1.7GB in memory unless
all the lines are mostly identical.

Comment: I think the asker needs a python solution.